# How to expire ASP Session if user will not interact with web page for specific time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

am using asp.net with C# for my project.

I want to expire `Session` if user will not interact with web site for specific time (i.e. say Session will expire if user will not interact with website in next 10 min.).

I use `web.config` configuration for `session timeout` as below.

`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10" />`

**Problem:** but it expire `session` after every 10 min. even if user is interacting with web site, The result is user have to logged-in again and again in after every 10 mins.

But, I want that `session` should expire in 10 min. if user is not interacting with web site within 10 min.

Comment: Is there also a 10-minute timeout specified somewhere else? For instance, in IIS in the Application Pool configuration?

Comment: @RoyDictus - no I didn't specified timeout in IIS Application Pool - should I?

Comment: No, but it looks like it's not your session state timeout that is the problem, but another one. Look everywhere in your application and your IIS configuration for timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using an authentication method?

If you are you can add the property

```
SlidingExpiration="true"
```

into the config, it resets the timeout if > half the time has elapsed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes this is what I want exact. It is working as I needed...!  Thanks :)

Comment: The session was probably still available, just the authentication timed out, those are seperate.

Answer (score 0):

you should check few things

> 1: Try using sessionstate mode=stateserver.
>
> 2:Your IIS Application pool reset or restart time.Is your Application pool restarting or recycling after fix period of time?
>
> 3: Check if you are using some where else session time out settings.It shold only be in web.config file.
>
> 4: Try using Server.Tranfer instead Response.Redirect() (Just try it. if above not works)